# w3 Validation help for blooger template

Tags: html, css

I am using a custom blogger template downloaded from other blog site and sites looks good from front but while checking for code errors in W3 validation i am getting too many errors where i am not good in HTML . can some one help me on this. below are the errors. URL is [plansdunia.com](http://www.plansdunia.com/)

Errors (770) · Hide all errors · Show all errors
A document must not include both a meta element with an http-equiv attribute whose value is content-type, and a meta element with a charset attribute.
Bad value **_ for attribute**  on element **: Expected a digit but saw**  instead. (2) · Hide all · Show all
Bad value 49px;  for attribute height on element img: Expected a digit but saw p instead.
Bad value 339px;  for attribute width on element img: Expected a digit but saw p instead.
Duplicate ID main.
Attribute  **not allowed on element**  at this point. (127) · Hide all · Show all
Attribute trbidi not allowed on element div at this point. (10)
Attribute height not allowed on element tr at this point. (117)
The  **attribute on the _** element is obsolete. Use CSS instead. (588) · Hide all · Show all
The cellpadding attribute on the table element is obsolete. Use CSS instead. (9)
The cellspacing attribute on the table element is obsolete. Use CSS instead. (9)
The border attribute on the table element is obsolete. Use CSS instead. (9)
The width attribute on the col element is obsolete. Use CSS instead. (38)
The height attribute on the td element is obsolete. Use CSS instead. (117)
The width attribute on the td element is obsolete. Use CSS instead. (400)
The align attribute on the img element is obsolete. Use CSS instead. (6)
Stray end tag col. (38)
Element img is missing required attribute src.
An img element must have an alt attribute, except under certain conditions. For details, consult guidance on providing text alternatives for images. (10)
Bad value dofollow for attribute rel on element a: The string dofollow is not a registered keyword.
Stray start tag script.
Warnings (6) · Hide all warnings · Show all warnings
The first occurrence of ID main was here.
The border attribute is obsolete. Consider specifying img { border: 0; } in CSS instead. (4)
This document appears to be written in English. Consider adding lang="en" (or variant) to the html start tag

Answer (score 0):

If it displays, properly, don't bother.  Honestly, it w3 validation does not make your website run better, it's just a standard that some places bother to enforce.  For instance, I can write code like:

```
<div>Hello World</div>
```

And it will behave exactly the same as:

```
<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div>Hello World</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

But, if you're really peeved by it, find a better template.  I'm sorry for being blunt, but no one on this website is going to help you fix 776 errors...